# What would be the best approach to solve this using OOP?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, data-structures

I bombed my interview after I got this OOP question from a company. Can one of you experts help solve this using Python? I had used switch cases (using python dictionary) to solve this problem without OOP.

```
Original string: abcdefghijklmn

Operations:F -> move curser forward, B -> move curse backward, R -> replace char

Operation string: F2B1F5Rw -> abcdefwhijklmn (expected output)

Moving forward by 2 chars, move backward by 1 char, move forward 5 chars, replace 1 char to be ‘w’

We can assume that curser is at first character at the beginning. How can I add more operations using OOP if required?
```

But apparently the interviewer wasnt too happy with my switch case approach, and as a follow up asked me to solve the problem using OOP. Any ideas how I could solve this without switch cases? A better approach using OOP principles or perhaps a better Data Structure I am not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind the 'dissatisfaction' does not seem to lie in `switch ... case` or its implementation using dictionary. To me it seems to be related to the concept of OOP. He/she might have wanted you to construct OOP structure of the task.

I would define a class with two state variables: one for the current string and one for the current position. Methods are the actions exerted on the string. For example, `replace(char)` (or `r(char)` in the code below) would replace the character at the current position with `char`. With these in mind, I define a class named `Editor`, create an object from that, and play with the object.

```
class Editor():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.pos = 0

    def f(self, step):
        self.pos += int(step)

    def b(self, step):
        self.pos -= int(step)

    def r(self, char):
        s = list(self.text)
        s[self.pos] = char
        self.text = ''.join(s)
        # could've just stored the list of chars (instead of string)
        # from the beginning, but that's rather a secondary issue.

    def run(self, command):
        command = list(command)
        while command:
            method = getattr(self, command.pop(0).lower())
            arg = command.pop(0)
            method(arg)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

text = 'abcdefghijklmn'
command = 'F2B1F5Rw'

ed = Editor(text)
ed.run(command)

print(ed)
```

An advantage of OOP is that you can flexibly add many more different (char-wise) actions like upper-lower conversion to the class. That, in my opinion, was what the interviewer was asking for.

Comment: Good solution. Can you also take care of the scenario where the input may not be a F, B, or R.

Comment: @JoeFerndz That's a good suggestion, but I'll leave that task to the OP ;)

Comment: Hey! good solution I am new to coding and I am a self-taught I understood the whole solution but can you please explain the run() function please.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows:

```
orig_string = 'abcdefghijklmn'
slist = list(orig_string)
opstr = 'F2B1F5Rw'
pos = 0
for w,p in zip(opstr[::2],opstr[1::2]):
    if w == 'F': pos += int(p)
    elif w == 'B': pos -= int(p)
    elif w == 'R': slist[pos] = p
    else: print ('Invalid Operational String... Aborting'); break
else:
    print (''.join(slist))
```

You don't need to use a switch case. You can use a if statement and take care of the current position based on the values.

If the value was: `opstr = 'F2B1F5RwX2'`, then the output will be: `Invalid Operational String... Aborting`

Comment: nice solution. But I was looking for an OOP approach, so accepting the other one.

Comment: Absolutely. I agree with the solution that @j1-lee provided. That's OOP solution. I was giving you a way to solve this so you know how to convert it to a OOP.